# Firebase Analytics debugview console not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've got Firebase Analytics configured for my Flutter app with -FIRDebugEnabled passed into the Xcode scheme. When I run the app, Firebase Analytics says that debug mode is enabled and that everything is working correctly. Events get logged with a successful upload.

However, nothing appears in Firebase Console. 0 active users, no devices found in DebugView and no events logged.

I ran `flutter clean`, reinstalled the app and still nothing is working. I've also added AdSupport.framework to the iOS app.

Anyone knows what might be happening?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I understand that's the case for events, but I'm not able to see my device in DebugView either despite the console saying that debug mode is enabled. Plus, I'm not able to see my device as an active device on analytics; it just shows 0 active devices.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I thought you were talking about Google Analytics.   You may want to edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Firebase uses the App ID in the configuration file to map the analytics data to your Firebase project. I would suggest double checking the config file you’re using in your app if it matches the one in your Firebase project

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue, and the following is what I did to resolve it.

#### Step 1

Open the Flutter project in Xcode by right-clicking the `ios` folder --> `open in Xcode`

#### Step 2

Click `Product` --> `Scheme` --> `Edit Scheme`

[image]

#### Step 3

Enable debug mode by adding the following:

```
-FIRDebugEnabled
-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
```

[image]

#### Step 4

Run the following commands:

```
$ flutter clean

$ flutter pub get

$ cd ios

$ pod install
```

#### Step 5

**Launch the app on Xcode** <-- IMPORTANT

Comment: Came here to comment this exact solution. Used it last night. Works. Only problem is with this method you may not be able to turn *off* debug mode. I removed all the flags, and it still was logging like crazy through the console... just forewarning.

Comment: Have you tried to add `-FIRDebugDisabled` to turn off debug mode?

Comment: Yes, so now I just run it via `Flutter run` which doesn't pass the args to XCode so it'll run normally

Comment: It should be noted that it is set once you launch the app in Xcode with the flag enabled. So you can then launch it in VS Code and the debug event will still go through. I'm unsure if clearing cache, etc, will require a new Xcode-triggered build. Also I don't believe you need the alternate "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" anymore. At least in the latest Flutter versions.